# Return 0 rows instead of something else SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this simple database:

```
SecretaryID username password
1           marpap    marpap
2           eleko     eleko
```

And I do this query:

```
select username, password 
from Secretaries 
where username='marpap' and
      Password='marpap'
```

but it return 0 rows instead of 1. What is the problem?

Comment: Probably because you don't have a username and password that are both, "marap". But without seeing your data, how do you expect to get a meaningful answer?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Just fixed it its my first question on stackoverflow so I am trying to conform

Comment: what do you get if you run `SELECT char_length(username), char_length(password) FROM secretaries WHERE secretaryid = 1`

Comment: Oh i get that the char length of username is 6 and the char length of password is 8...pretty akward..

Comment: You can try `where LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) = 'marpap'`. There 2 more characters that could be spaces. If they aren't spaces you can use ascii to find them

Comment: Ok I just fixed id char length showed my that i had a " " when i inserted password so the query couldnt find my row...Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to remove spaces before or after your string.

```
where LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) = 'marpap'
and password = 'marpap'
```